# Feature Spec passes every time in RSpec, Fails in Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, jenkins

I have a users factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :aliases => [:assignee] do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    sequence(:username) { |n| "foo#{n}@example.com" }
    profile

  end
end
```

And a jobs factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    association :assignee, factory: :user
    description "MyText"
    completion_comment "MyText"
    job_type "MyString"
    ...
  end
end
```

Which are loaded into my jobs_feature_spec_helper:

```
def add_valid_job
  click_job
  within("#add_job") do
    select 'foo1@example.com', from: 'Assignee'
    fill_in_html("job__textarea", {:with => job[:description]})
    click_button "Save"
  end
end
```

My feature page spec passes in RSpec on my machine, but my employer sent me an email saying that the spec failed in Jenkins. Here's the message he sent:

```
Unable to find option "foo1@example.com <mailto:foo1@example.com>"
./spec/support/job_feature_spec_helpers.rb:11:in `block in add_valid_job'
./spec/support/job_feature_spec_helpers.rb:10:in `add_valid_job'
./spec/features/jobs/edit_job_line_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

So, it appears that when Jenkins runs the spec, it's not finding the assignee from the drop-down list, yet RSpec is. I have never personally used Jenkins, so if anyone has any advice that may help, I'd appreciate hearing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about the sequence number. You can't use hardcorded `'foo1@example.com'` in test.

There is no guarantee that the sequence number will start from 1. I have no time to figure out the reason, but just know the fact. In my tests I often see it from tens after running several tests.

I would suggest you to get the email from an existing user in db, created by FactoryGirl.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even notice that I had the '1' hard-coded...it's funny this passes in RSpec each time and fails in Jenkins, but you're probably right.

Comment: @aceofbassgreg, yes it could pass sometimes, but not reliable. Better to change that.

Comment: The reason it passes in RSPec is b/c I'm running it in isolation (just these specs) as opposed to running Guard. I'm sure it'd fail in Guard as well.

Comment: Instead of using an existing user in the DB, I was able to instead use the dynamically-created username from FactoryGirl. I did this by adding an argument to `add_valid_job(current_user)` and by revising the `current_user` helper. I think this is better than relying on an actual user (though it was trickier to set up).

Comment: Yes, I meant the similar as yours :) The "existing users" is created by FG a nd data is set through variable. Actually there is no other "existing" user except what FG created, since the db is cleaned on every new example.

Answer (score 1):

Although this was not your issue, one possible cause of getting different results between jenkins and test environments is using `different DBs` on each.

In my case I was using `sqlite` on jenkins and `postgres` on test, and that was generating different results.

Locally you can run

```
RAILS_ENV="jenkins" bundle exec rspec
```

to run specs on jenkins environment.